# Screenshot of Postman does not contain a window frame nor shadow

Tags: applications, apps, screenshot

Elementary contains the defualt app "Screenshot", which allows to take screenshots of apps' windows.
When I take a screenshot of say Files app, it looks like that:

[image]

However, a screenshot of Postman app looks like this:

[image]

In reality, the app looks as below:

[image]

Why there is no window frame nor shadow around?
Unfortunatly, I do not recall how I installed this app. I think I did it via Flathub store.

Comment: I'm also getting that for all non-curated apps. Went through a dozen different screenshot tools and some of them are doing the same and some cannot even detect an application window.
Unfortunately, while there are few screencasting tools made for eOS, there are no eOS apps for taking a screenshot :-(

Comment: That's a shame. This is one of these small issues that accumulate, one after the other, making it really hard, or just annoying to work daily on Linux-based systems :(

Comment: Not so much Linux-based system but very much elementaryOS. You should try Ubuntu or UbuntuBudgie and you'll find far fewer annoyances. elementaryOS is quite specific and one needs to have a reason to use it (not that I'm saying there are no reasons).

Comment: @Guest Believe me, I tried multiple times many distros. Most of them just look awful, I find elementaryOS the only one that looks acceptable. It's not only eOS that has some small problems. Ubuntu also is full of these weird unexpected small bugs here and there. Say whatever you want about Windows or macOS, but in the end they are so much more polished when it comes to end user experience (not talking about Windows GUI design here)

Comment: BTW, I submitted a bug in elementary/screenshot repo: https://github.com/elementary/screenshot/issues/197